# How to sort headings in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to alphabetically sort headings inside a Word 2010 file?

Comment: I think instead of restating the question more explanation of what you are trying and possibly sample data would be better.

Comment: @BradPatton, what is unclear or missing in my first-line question ?

Comment: The quality standards flag was because the question repeated the title. I was trying to explain that and ask for more info. Do you mean all Headings or just those of a certain level? Do you want the text below them sorted or just the headings?

Comment: @BradPatton, thanks for your efforts, but if someone says `sort headings` it should mean `all headings`. Yes, of course, I want to sort the heading's belonging content

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to a copy of Word 2010 to confirm, but this works in Word 2007:

1. Change to outline view, and limit the display to level 1 headings
2. Select all the visible text
3. Sort the selection (click the sort button on the toolbar)

Comment: Lorax, it works only for particular (selected level). Must I repeatidly do the same for each level ?

Comment: @Buena, yes you'll need to do it separately for each level. As others have mentioned, you may want to give a more detailed description of what you are trying to achieve and why (maybe include an example). There may be an easier way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Lorax, my goal is to sort headings, and not to sort a particular level of headings. And it should be clear from the sentence: `How to sort headings`. Anyway, i see - it's not possible. Closed, for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Buena, you may know exactly what you expect in your head, however from the little info you have communicated to us it is hard for us to know this. Under "Show Levels" have you tried selecting "All Levels" before you select all and run the sort? Does this help?